# How to make multiple screen support in android?

Tags: android, screen, multiscreen

I designed an app which works well with 320*480. My problem is that when I install and use my app on small or large displays such as 240*320, 480*800 I'm experiencing problems with the alignment of the components.

I know something that I have to design separate layouts for each screen size.

Comment: Consider visiting http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

Comment: Also there are lots of questions regarding this topics on google as well as SO. So you can try as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official answer : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
Nothing to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the developer tutorial links which will state you and guide you how to make layout without using static width and height also how to support multiple screen using that layout.

[Declaring the layout and design guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

[Support multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the following web site for developing multiple screen support application.

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html (Follow the sub links also)
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html